# Heroku+Node.js How to clone node_modules?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, node-modules

Have an old project. It is based on old modules, which are deleted from npm repos, or on modules which are based on modules which are delete from repos )
So, project cloned, and `npm install` says `not found`. But on heroku it works, because have been deployed 2 years ago. I tried to edit .gitignore but it does no effect. Git does not contain node_modules folder.

Question: How to clone node_modules from Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get into a shell of your Heroku dyno:

```
$ heroku run bash
```

Then you can tar the `node_modules` folder:

```
$ tar -czvpf node_modules.tar.gz node_modules
```

Then scp your new archive to another machine:

```
$ scp node_modules.tar.gz user@host:.
```

Comment: `heroku run bash
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.`

Comment: Yeah, you need to be in the local folder on your machine where you have the matching git repo.  Once you're in that folder, try the heroku command.

Comment: Is there alternative to scp?

Comment: You could use ftp or rsync.  Although probably the easiest thing to do outside of scp would be to just move node_modules.tar.gz into the public folder of your node.js app and then download it with a browser.